ReferenceError: Highlight is not defined, we use CSS Custom Highlight API in a fn to highlight query str in texts, how do I unit test it with jest?
I have this highlighting function in a file and I want to unit test it with jest:
export function highlightTextFunction(searchingStr: string, rootEl: HTMLElement) {
  if (!searchingStr || !rootEl) {
    CSS.highlights.clear()
    return
  }

  const treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(rootEl, NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT)
  const allTextNodes: Node[] = []
  let currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()
  while (currentNode) {
    const parent = currentNode.parentNode

    if (
      currentNode instanceof Node &&
      parent instanceof Element &&
      getComputedStyle(parent).display !== 'none' &&
      parent.getAttribute('data-test') !== 'no-users-message' // don't consider "keine ergebniese" message
    ) {
      allTextNodes.push(currentNode)
    }
    currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()
  }

  const allWords: { parentNode: Node; offset: number }[] = []
  for (const textNode of allTextNodes) {
    const text = textNode.textContent || ''
    for (const word of text.matchAll(new RegExp(searchingStr, 'ig'))) {
      allWords.push({
        parentNode: textNode,
        offset: word.index,
      })
    }
  }

  const ranges: Range[] = []
  for (const { parentNode, offset } of allWords) {
    const range = new Range()
    range.setStart(parentNode, offset)
    range.setEnd(parentNode, offset + searchingStr.length)
    ranges.push(range)
  }

  const highlight = new Highlight(...ranges)
  CSS.highlights.set('search-highlight', highlight)
}

I created a test:
import { highlightTextFunction } from './highlight-text.function'
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing'

class MockHighlight {
}

describe('Highlight Text Function', () => {
  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [{provide: Highlight, useValue: MockHighlight}]
    })
  })
  
  it('highlightTextFunction should return true if no value provided', () => {
    const htmlElement = document.createElement('div')
    htmlElement.innerText = 'test'
    highlightTextFunction('test', htmlElement)
    expect(htmlElement).toBe('highlighted')
  })
})

It isn't working because jest fails with "ReferenceError: Highlight is not defined"
I've tried to add "dom" to tsconfig.spec.json lib and types, both didn't work. I've tried to create the MockHighlight class by myself and provide it. It's not working. I want to ensure, that the function does it's job, how do I do that?
